# VIM Relace all <a ...> and </a>?

Tags: regex, vim

Sorry this might be a simple question, but I could not figure it out. What I need is to filter out all the `<a href...>` and `</a>` strings out from a html text. Not sure what regular expression I should use? I tried the following search without any luck:

```
/<\shref^(>)>
```

what I mean here is to search for any string starting with "< href" and any string not containing '>' and finally '>'. My search code is not working. What is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for it should be `<\shref[^>]*>`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use non-greedy matching:

```
/<a\shref.\{-}>
```

Comment: I am confused by your pattern. Can you explain "\{-}"? "\{" looks like escape or match '{', then '-'. '}' has not matched left one.

Comment: `\{-}` (or `\{-\}` has special meaning in vim: it's like `*`, but it's non-greedy.  It only matches the least amount of data to make the whole pattern match.  In vim, type `:h pattern` and then search for `{-}` for more information.

Comment: Very cool! A very nice alternative to search. I like it. For multiple line case, "<a\_.\{-}>" will match <a cross lines. I found \_. is for matching any char including newline.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:

```
/<a\shref[^>]+>
```

where [] is a set and ^ is not.